# Numpy Minimize COBYLA Constraints

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, constraints, minimize

I am using scipy.minimize with the COBYLA method, but I seem to be unable to write the constraints properly because when I check the values of the objective function, they do not respect those constraints.

Basically, the objective function accepts an array as argument, that must follow two constraints:

1. Each value in the array must be greater than 0
2. The sum of the values must be inferior to 1

So far I wrote it this way:

```
constraints = [{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: 1 - sum(x)},
               {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x[0]},
               {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x[1]}]
```

However, sometimes I get values greater than 1...

Here is an example:

```
from __future__ import division
from math import pow, exp
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

nbStudy = 3
nbCYP = 2
raucObserved = [3.98, 2.0, 0.12]
IXmat = np.matrix([[-0.98, 0], [-0.3, -0.98], [7.7, 4.2]])

NBITER = 50
estimatedCR = []
raucPred = []
varR = [0.0085, 0.0048, 0.0110]
sdR = [0.0922, 0.0692, 0.1051]

cnstrts = [{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: 1 - sum(x)},
               {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x}]


def fun(CR):
    dum = []

    for i in range(nbStudy):
        crix = 0

        for j in range(nbCYP):
            crix += CR[j] * IXmat[i, j]

        raucPredicted = 1 / (1 + crix)
        dum.append(pow((np.log(raucPredicted) - np.log(raucObservedBiased[i])), 2) / varR[i])

    output = np.sum(dum)

    return output


for iter in range(NBITER):
    raucObservedBiased = []

    for k in range(nbStudy):
        raucObservedBiased.append(raucObserved[k] * exp(sdR[k] * np.random.normal()))

    initialCR = np.matrix([[(1 / nbCYP) * np.random.uniform()], [(1 / nbCYP) * np.random.uniform()]])

    output = minimize(fun, initialCR, method='COBYLA', constraints=cnstrts)
    estimatedCR.append(output.x)
```

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: I would put some effort into a minimal working example, that way it is more probable to get some help.

Comment: Well I was hoping to get insights from knowledgeable people on how the constraints are supposed to be written since the official documentation is so light on the subject and I didn't find anything helpful on the web so far... 

But if you really need a working example I'll try to produce one (my real code implies a lot of side computations...)

Comment: I added an example. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not checking that the solver converged (output.success == True) --- and in your case it does not converge. If there is no convergence, nothing is guaranteed about the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently a version problem, the issue has been fixed since. I was using Python 2.7 and Scipy 0.13...